# Python to create new fields in many layers / QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, field-calculator

I have a number of line layers on which I need to perform the same task: add 4 columns with the start and end points of each line.

The expressions that I use to do this are:

```
$xat(0)
$xat(-1)
$yat(0)
$yat(-1)
```

However, I must create a new column and update it for every layer, but I am sure that it can be automated.   Any ideas on how to perform the creation of 4 new columns on every layer in the layers panel in QGIS?

Comment: This can be done using pyqgis.  To get answers to your question you will need to provide a code attempt for doing this task.  Please edit your question and include your code attempt and let us know where you get stuck and you should receive feedback.

Comment: You could also achieve this by creating a **model** from the _Processing Toolbox_, this is useful if you don't know Python. Here's a couple of links which you might find helpful: [Automating Complex Workflows using Processing Modeler](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/processing_graphical_modeler.html), [QGIS Quick Tip - Building a Processing Model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyPW8mzssZE).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you could create a **model** from the *Processing Toolbox* but if you want to create a script, you could use the following which creates the `start_lat` field and updates it for each layer (comments are included which hopefully will help):

```
# Import required module to create field
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

# For each layer in panel
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    # Add a real field (which uses decimal)
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("start_lat", QVariant.Double) ] )
    # Update attribute table with new field
    layer.updateFields()
    # Begin editing of layer and finish loop with saving edits
    with edit(layer):
        # Let `idx` = field with name "start_lat"
        idx = layer.fieldNameIndex( "start_lat" )
        # Define expression
        e = QgsExpression( """ $x_at(0) """ )
        e.prepare( layer.pendingFields() )
        # For each feature in layer
        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            # Apply expression
            f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
            # Update attribute table
            layer.updateFeature(f)
```

You could then repeat the above by adapting it to create the other 3 fields or extend the loops and create all 4 fields at once.

Comment: the code runs without errors but creates an attribute field full of NULL values.   However, manually entering same expression `x_at(0)` in the field calculator produces an attribute field filled with the right values....

Comment: @the_darkside - Are you running it from the Python Console or from a script?

Comment: I am running it from the Python Console in QGIS

Comment: Does this happen with other line layers also? I just tested this again (directly copying/pasting the code) and it works. I used QGIS 2.14.3-Essen.

Comment: I am running the same version of QGIS, and the same thing happened with a different line layer... I am just getting blank columns

Comment: Are the CRS for the layers in meters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41708/discussion-between-the-darkside-and-joseph).